# Click event not working on objects added dynamically in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, events, click

I've a HTML page where I'm adding an icon file to DIVs dynamically. This image serves as close icon and has a predefined class, say, 'close'. To this class I've attached the click event like

```
$('.close').click(function({
     alert('You chose to delete this image');
});
```

this works fine for the script that is loaded on page load. However, when I attach the same icon to other DIVs, the click event doesn't seem to trigger. There's no error in firebug. I don't know what's wrong!

Comment: try : `$('.close').on("click" , function()`

Comment: the event is working for objects loaded on runtime!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate on document or the closest static element

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    alert("You chose to delete this image");
});
```

Comment: You were faster  :) +1

Answer (score 1):

You need to do event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    //rest of the code

}
```